# Добавить id для dto

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Есть рест контроллер:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private final UserServiceImpl userService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/create", consumes = "application/json")
    public void create(@RequestBody UserCreateRequestDto userDto) {
        userService.create(userDto);
    }
}
```

Метод принимает dto объект. В нем отсутствуют поля такие как id, roles и т.д

Как преобразовать в доменный класс, чтобы hibernate сам назначил ему айдишник и прочее?

Comment: Используйте MapStruct. Инструкции у нему можно найти в Интернете. Просто так сохранить в БД DTO нельзя. Нужно сущность @Entity. Почитайте про Spring Data JPA

Answer (score -1):

1. Вы должны иметь понимание, что такое слои в **SOA**(сервис-оринетированная архитектура).
2. Понимать для чего нужны **DTO** (это контейнеры для передачи данных между слоем бизнес-логики (**Service laye**r) и слоем доступа к базе данных (**DAO**). Также из контейнера DTO данные для возврата ответа клиенту сериализуются (например, используется JAKSON) и отправляются клиенту. Когда запрос приходит, происходит десериализация данных и они перекладываются в DTO-объект. Трансформация (перевод из DTO в Entity и обратно) - должна происходить на **Service layer**.
3. Понимать, что **Hibernate** это поставщик **ORM**-системы.
4. Понимать, что такое **JPA** (это ряд правил и рекомендаций (в общем смысле), который обязывает стандартизировать различные фреймворки **ORM**-систем), что позволяет не делая почти никаких изменений в коде, подключать различных вендоров **ORM**-систем).
5. Понимать как происходит генерация id, для сущности, которая готовится для  сериализации в базу данных.
6. Понимать, что такое **сериализация** и **десериализация** в плоскости работы вашего приложения.
7. **Id** может даже формироваться вашим приложением (например, 16-х значной строкой - тип **UUID**)
8. Важно понимать что такое **Persistence context**, в рамках **Hibernate**.

```java
     @Entity
     @Table(name = "product")
     public class Product {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;
```

Это лишь малая часть настройки. Важно понимать, как это работает на самом деле (есть отличия в настройке **ID**, для разных поставщиков **JDBC API**).

9. Для передачи данных между **Dto** и **Entity** нужны трансформеры, один из таких - **MapStruct**.

> В нем отсутствуют поля такие как id, roles и т.д

При создании записи в базе данных, какая та часть данных предоставляется клиентом, который делает запрос на сохранения данных в базу данных, а какая то часть будет заполнена вашим приложением, например, набор ролей :
В DTO будет указан список ролей доступа к системе, для текущей записи, а ваше приложение, полученную информацию может преобразовать, например, загрузив список возможных "ролей доступа", сформировать для текущего запроса роли доступа в соответсвии с форматом, как это должно быть сохранено в базе данных. Если вы учитесь, то спросите преподавателя - как это сделать. Если стажируетесь, то ментор должен это все разъяснить.

На ваш вопрос, однозначный ответ не стоит давать. Вы должны разобраться в том, что делаете. Не получится просто подставлять шаблонный код и программировать, нужно понимать смысл того, как фреймоворки "за кулисами" выполняют поставленные задачи, это поможет быстрее найти ошибки, в случае сбоя системы.

Comment: и давно DTO передает данные в промежутке слоев сервиса и базы?
DTO отвечает за трансфер объектов со слоя контроллеров до сервисов, то есть от слоя близкому к пользователю до бизнес-логики, ИМХО

Comment: зачем новичку советовать MapStruct, когда он должен научиться сам писать свои toDTO методы?
Вы не компетентны в данном вопросе и оперируете заученными понятиями

Comment: Artur Vartanyan
Не предирайтесь к словам и вчитайтесь. Когда вы получаете сущность. Вы на слое бизнес логики с ней работаете. С помощью трансформера, вы передаете это в контейнер DTO из которого происходит забор данных их сериализация и отправка клиенту. Я бы советовал вам подучить эту тему самому и разобраться что к чему

Comment: повторюсь еще раз, пришел на форум человек который не совсем понимает зачем нужны ДТО, просит помочь с вопросом, а в ответ получает кучу информации не связанной с темой. Идет "умное объяснение" что такое UUID, советы по mapStruct-у, сюда даже persistenceContext умудрились добавить. Это не поможет человеку, а только запутает, так как для объяснения ДТО на начальном этапе не нужно заучивать весь Hibernate. Человек отсюда уйдет с еще большими вопросами. Поэтому не нужно отвечать людям с позиции своего возвышения. Объясните простым языком, тогда он реализует что хочет и на практике получит ответы

Comment: Тогда прошу вас объяснить это коллеге простым языком.

Comment: @ArturVartanyan у меня к вам насущный вопрос, а зачем ему объяснять это всё доступным языком? Человек, задавший вопрос, не понимает почему у него не проходит сохранение - можно сделать вывод, что он вообще не понимает с чем имеет дело. Давайте все вместе расскажем ему как сделать правильно, чтобы всё заработало и что дальше? Ему В ЛЮБОМ случае нужно это всё выучить и понять.

Comment: @ArturVartanyan и вообще зачем он начал создавать DTO-объекты, когда не имеет представления о более важных вещах? Приложение может и без DTO функционировать, это аспект чисто архитектурный. Ему указали куда нужно идти дальше и пускай себе сидит учит